# Azure Cognitive Search: Getting entire document as a search result from azure blob storage

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blob storage to store my documents. When I am searching for a particular topic present in the document, I am getting the entire document(.pdf) as a search result.

Now my requirement is to:

1. Open the PDF in which a match is found.
2. Go to the specific page number where searched is matched
3. Highlight the matched text.

To do such a thing, do we need any kind of custom skill that should be added in a skill set.

Comment: you can find a good sample https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSearch_JFK_Files/

Answer (score 0):

In the [Azure Search Power Skills](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills), there is a custom skill that will help with that: the hOCR generator at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-power-skills/blob/master/Vision/HocrGenerator/README.md.  The hOCR format is what allows us to provide highlighting of documents in the [JFK demo](https://jfk-demo.azurewebsites.net/).